# Move repository GitHub to GitLab - no option for GitHub on Import

Tags: github, import, gitlab, repository

Trying to move a GitHub Repository and all supporting branches to GitLab, but do not see an option to import from GitHub only GL to GL.  Please help !   Thanks

[GitLab Import options][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfR0q.jpg)GitLab Import Screen

Answer (score 4):

An administrator of your GitLab instance needs to enable GitHub as an import source at `Admin Area > Settings > General > Visibility and access controls`.

[image: Import sources]